# Can you test for regular expression match without using double brackets?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

As far as I understand (feel free to correct me, I'm new to shell scripting), the bracket `[` is a Unix command and also an alternative to the `test` command which allows you to test for a condition (returning `0` if condition is `true` and `1` otherwise)

Double brackets `[[` is a keyword which allows you to do more complex condition evaluations. For example, the test against a regular expression.

If I understand correctly, double brackets `[[` can potentially have the portability issues depending on a shell where the script is executed (for example, not supported by Bourne shell).

Therefore a question. If I want to test the variable for regular expression, is it possible to do using the `test` command (or the single bracket `[` command)?

Answer (score 1):

Traditionally `test [` were different names (hardlinks) for *one* program, which did exactly the same thing(s) in both cases except for `[` requiring the trailing `]`; today they are usually shell builtins that still do the same except for `]`. **That program or those builtins do NOT do regular expressions.**

The POSIX (and traditional) ways to test a regular expression are `expr grep sed awk`. The first does only few things including regexp, rather similar  to `test/[` and also `[[`. The second at core does only regexp, but with a lot of surrounding options. The last two do a lot of things *including* regexp, but if that's all you want you can do only that. Another common but not POSIX method is `perl`.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Let me know if I understood this right. 1) I can't check for regex with `test` or `[ ]`. 2) The most common/traditional ways to do it is with `expr grep sed awk` or `[[ ]]` or `perl`